# VS2012 reserved word color for .template files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, colors, visual-studio-2012, reserved-words

I am in a C++ class and my professor has given us some starter code to implement a graph.

She has given us a `.template` file and wants us to run it in Visual Studio 2012, however VS2012 doesn't seem to recognize the `.template` file as C++ code so does not color the C++ reserved words at all.

The program still compiles and runs, but it is more difficult to code when I can't see any of the reserved words in color. Is there any way to make VS2012 color the reserved words in `.template` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Sure. Just rename it to have a `.cpp` extension.</s>

Or, alternatively, Visual Studio offers functionality that will allow you to map a custom extension to a particular editing experience. Go into your Visual Studio options and navigate to Text Editor > File Extension.

[image: Visual Studio > Options > Text Editor > File Extension]

Here, you can add `template` as a file extension and map it to the Microsoft Visual C++ editor.

Comment: .hpp is probably better if it has templates

Comment: I'm going to guess that OP doesn't mean `template` in the context of C++, but rather "template" as in the context of starter code.

Comment: @Pubby, I think it's just a skeleton file.

Comment: So am I out of luck then on keeping it a .template file and having the reserved words highlighted?

Comment: Actually, there is another way. Let me update my post for you.